# webview application to scan qr code

Tags: android, webview, qr-code

I have a webview app in android now my question is how do i allow this app for the webview to access the camera and to scan a qr barcode? and access it?

I did look at [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html).

I've found some code about how to access the camera to take photo's or videos, but don't see anything about **scanning qr code**.

How can I do this?

Comment: You have a webView and there is a button or anything on that webView, after clicking that button you want to scan qr or barcode , is that what you want ?

Comment: tag are very important. And format a little better please.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom client to intercept the request

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, WebResourceRequest) {
    // here you try to understand if you are loading the "open camera" link
    return true; 
}
```

[WebViewClient Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)

Or, you can set a HTML form with 'file' input type, then handle the behaviour in

```
boolean onShowFileChooser (WebView webView, 
                ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, 
                WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
```

[WebChromeClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html#onShowFileChooser(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Candroid.net.Uri[]%3E,%20android.webkit.WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams))

Answer (score 0):

You can scan the QR code and get the result in the app. It will not be from the webview, instead it will be a part of the app like a button click from the toolbar or something.

If that is what you are looking for, you can find a sample scanner app tutorial [here](https://github.com/Rohan-Kumar/Barcode-QR-code-Scanner)